# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS suddenly slowed down

Tags: 14.04, swap

I have been using 14.04 LTS for a couple of months and it run perfectly. It suddenly slowed down like hell. I find a sloution by decreasing swapping from 60 to 10. But if swapping at 60 was really a problem, why is it that it worked perfectly for so long?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was due to a faulty HDD

Answer (score 0):

10 And 60 as swap! is than in GB???

How much ram you have?

having a slow OS without any changes maybe caused by low HD space.
Try checking free space available using `df -h` and post the result back please.

also can you post the result of `top` command?

Please note that this can also be because of a faulty HDD.

can you please post the result of `dd if=/dev/zero of=speetest bs=1M count=100 conv=fdatasync`

Comment: He's talking about the Swappiness setting, not the size of his swap partition.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, Thanks for the info. then mostly you have high ram usage > 50-60% most of the time which on 60 Swappiness setting will tend to do a lot of read/write into swap partition which will get things slower, at 10 your computer will start to use swap at ~85%.